# when using a url that get a random image every time on multiple widgets, the same image result shows in all of them

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

all my Firestore documents contain a field called `image_path`, which has the Unsplash random source URL, https://source.unsplash.com/random/

[image]

as you can test, every time you opened that link it gives a different random image.
but in my flutter app, in the `Image.network` `Row`'s children in `SingleChildScrollView`, all of them get the same random URL,

```
       SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Row(
              children: List.generate(lengthOfDocuments),
              (index) => ImageBox(
                documentsList[index]["image_path"], // image_path == https://source.unsplash.com/random/
              ),
            ),
          );
```

but they show the same image :

[image]

**what I am expecting:**
that all images should get a randomly different image from that URL

what can be the reason for this behavior, and am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be some kind of caching happening in the browser or on unsplash end.

Try making the url unique for each index like so:

```
documentsList[index]["image_path"] + `?index=${index}`
```

If that doesn't change between page reloads then you could make the query param a random # or string.

Comment: Perfectly working now, Thank you TJ H.

Comment: No problem! Seems fun and good luck with the rest of the app.